# SSRS Matrix Variance Calculation - Columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am trying to calculate the variance between two dataset grouping.  My datasets are my fiscal years. The fiscal years have month.  On the left, the report will only show current month data.  To the right, there will be a year-to-date comparison.

I would like to calculate the difference between the months of each dataset.  How would I achieve this?[image]

Looking forward to your responses.  Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to specify the dataset in the SUM. Did you try `=SUM(Amount,"dataset1") - SUM(Amount,"dataset2")`?

Comment: I am sorry but I should have been more alert when posting this.  The DataSet in my report is a field.  It's not a separate SSRS dataset.

Comment: Any help?  Anybody? Please?